# Swift MapKit: Parsing data to next VC from annotationView

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to parse an array of information to the next VC when the users tap the rightCalloutAccessoryView?

Lets say I have this set of information that I need to parse over:

```
[name: "XXX",gender: "YYY",lat: 11.1111,lon: 22.2222]
```

and in the next VC we will display these info in a 'profile page' manner. My implementation thus far is as such:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "PersonIcon")

        return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            viewActivity()
        }
}

func viewActivity() {
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ActivityView") as! ActivityViewController
        controller.parsedInfo = /*parsedInfo*/
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

EDIT:

Code for addAnnotation in viewDidLoad:

```
FIRHelperClient.sharedInstance.getLocationsForActivities(ref) { (results, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {

            for result in results! {
                guard let lat = result.lat, let lon = result.lon, let activity = result.searchActivities else {
                    print("locationForActivities did not return lat or lon")
                    return
                }

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                annotation.title = activity
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using prepareForSegue method? There you can pass your data to next controller with ease.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the code you have now... why can't you do the parsing in the `viewActivity` function and pass it like `controller.parsedInfo = `..... does the controller UIViewController have a property named parsedInfo??

Comment: My annotations are pulled in from Firebase, and tapping on different annotationView would be tapping on different 'parsedInfo'. I have no idea how to parse its respective info through annotationView to the next VC. I have added in the code for addAnnotation